# Issue with Twitter 4j callback on Android

Tags: java, android

I have successfully integrated twitter in my app but now I want to open next activity upon successful login.

How do I implement a call back method? i use on Activity result for twitter but it does not gives any error but also its does not works kindly tell me the right way to solve it thanks in advance....

```
package com.example.android.accenturefeed;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClient;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthService;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInRequestToken;
import com.linkedin.platform.LISessionManager;
import com.linkedin.platform.errors.LIAuthError;
import com.linkedin.platform.listeners.AuthListener;
import com.linkedin.platform.utils.Scope;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public ProgressDialog pdialog;
    public AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1901;
    private LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService;
    private LinkedInApiClientFactory factory;
    private LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
    private LinkedInApiClient client;




    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "my_consumer_key";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "my_consumer_secret";

    // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

    // Login button
    Button TwitterLoginButton;

    // Twitter
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;

    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //        for facebook signin
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
        final LoginActivity thisActivity = this;


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


//        for twitter login
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

        TwitterLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
        TwitterLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                Configuration configuration = builder.build();

                TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                twitter = factory.getInstance();

                try {
                    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });


//        for google signin
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

//        for logging out from facebook
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

//        checks internet
        if (isNetworkAvailable()==true){

            //linkedin button
            Button libutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLinkedin);
            libutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //linkedin signin
                    LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(thisActivity, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthSuccess() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                            info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
                        }
                    }, true);
                }
            });


//            google login button
            SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

//            shows error
            info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);

//            facebook login button
            loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
//                    info.setText(
//                            "User ID: "
//                                    + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
//                                    + "\n" +
//                                    "Auth Token: "
//                                    + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
//                    );

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                    info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    info.setText("Login attempt failed.");

                }
            });


            Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        final EditText user =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextentername);
        final EditText pass =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextenterpassword);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
                                      String givenUsername = user.getText().toString();
                                      String givenPassword = pass.getText().toString();

                                      if (givenUsername.isEmpty() || givenPassword.isEmpty()) {
                                          TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
                                          textView.setText("Username & password required!");


                                      } else {
                                          pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "Authenticating", "Please wait...");

                                          sendLoginRequest(givenUsername, givenPassword);
                                      }
                                  }

                                  private void sendLoginRequest(final String givenUsername, final String givenPassword) {


                                      SendLoginRequestAsyncTask asyncTask = (SendLoginRequestAsyncTask) new SendLoginRequestAsyncTask(new SendLoginRequestAsyncTask.AsyncResponse() {


                                          @Override
                                          public void processFinish(String name) {
                                              if (name.isEmpty()) {

                                                  TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
                                                  textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d41a14"));
                                                  textView.setText("Username or Password Is Incorrect!");
                                                  pdialog.dismiss();
                                              } else {
                                                  Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
                                                  intent.putExtra("username", name);
                                                  pdialog.dismiss();
                                                  startActivity(intent);
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }).execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);

                                  }
                              }
        );
    }

        else {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check Your Internet Connection");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    private Scope buildScope() {
        return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

//        for twitter result
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("KEY_URI"));
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(LoginActivity.URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                    try {
                        AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                        LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }


//        for google
          if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                handleSignInResult(result);
            }
//        for facebook
            else {
                callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
            //forlinkedin
            LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }



//    for google to open next activity or not
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
//            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
//                @Override
//                public void onResult(Status status) {
//                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
//                }
//            });
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //    checks Internet is available or not
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;

    }

//    for google sign in button on click method
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            // ...
        }
    }

//    google sign in method
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

// google connection failed method
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all the intents from your code except the one from this:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("KEY_URI"));
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(LoginActivity.URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
                try {
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                    LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Just keep the intent portion in order to go to the next activity in OnActivityResult itself, remove any other intent calls from your entire code and try running the app again.

Comment: what will be WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE .error is cannot resolve WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE. and what will be "KEY_URI" in                 final Uri uri = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("KEY_URI"));

Comment: thats used in order to authenticate via webview. what exactly are you using to authenticate your app. please post your complete code. I'll give you the solution accordingly.

Comment: i am integrating twitter in my application when the user successfully logged in with twitter than on result i want to open another activity

Comment: i posted my complete code i also integrated facebook,linkedin,gmail for my app they all works fine but the only problem is with twitter when i click the sign up with twitter button i open new activity but after login it return to my main activity does nothing and does not gives any error tell me how can i go to next activity on successful login with twitter.....